# Code explanation required

Tags: c#, .net

```
new AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne(Period);
```

What is purpose of this code? Why not use Thread.Sleep instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that code is stupid. Since the `AutoResetEvent` is `new` in this line, nothing else has a reference to the same `AutoResetEvent`, so nothing is going to signal it. A `Sleep` would be simpler.

When used *correctly*, use of an `AutoResetEvent` allows you to wait for something else to "open the gate" (assuming it wasn't already open), or timeout. Note also that the gate closes automatically each time `WaitOne` is successful.

However, this code *does not* use it correctly, and does not allow for this.

Comment: I bet there's a comment above that code line `// because it works`